# Greasemonkey Click Button without ID or Name

Tags: automation, greasemonkey

I'm trying to autoclick this button with greasemonkey. I tried to find a reference to this button with document.getElementsBy[ClassName/Name/TagName] with ClassName i find buttons but not the one i need. Any ideas how i can automate his click-event?

```
<button type="button" class="ml-2 mt-2 v-btn v-btn--depressed theme--light v-size--default amber darken-1 white--text ">
    ::before
    <span class="v-btn__content">
        <!----> 
        Überspringen
        <i aria-hidden="true" class="v-icon notranslate v-icon--right material-icons theme--light">
            redo
            ::after
        </i>
        <!---->
    </span>
</button>
```

[Screenshot from Firefox Inspector with Click Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k06in.png)

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

Just use `xpath` for element searching:

`document.evaluate(XPATH, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;`

1. You can use `class` parameter instead `id` or `name`:

- xpath: `//button[@class='ml-2 mt-2 v-btn v-btn--depressed theme....']`

If you do not need to use all value, you can use `contains` keyword:

- xpath:
  `//button[contains(@class, 'ml-2 m2-2')]`
- css:
  `button[class*='ml-2 m2-2']`

Of course, this value must be unique.

2. You can search child element and return back to the parent:

- `//button/span[@class='v-btn__content']/i/../..`

3. You can use text for searching (bad practics if location possible to change)

- `//button/span[text()='Überspringen']/..`

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer so far. I get an "Uncaught ReferenceError: XPATH is not defined" when i use document.evaluate.
In the FireFox-Inspektor i can copy the CSS-Selektor and XPATH is there a way i can use this as variable on the click listener in tampermonkey?

Comment: You need to use real xpath except XPATH word (I provided examples, try `//button/span[text()='Überspringen']/..` or `//button[contains(@class, 'ml-2 m2-2')]/span/i`. You can sure - just press F12 for DevTools calling, select `Elements` tab (For Chrome), and press `CTRL+F`. Now you can paste any xpathes I provided and see the result (if you have more than 1 in result - you need to add additional restrictions

Comment: For example, try paste to the console:
`document.evaluate("(//button[contains(@class, 'ml-2 m2-2')]/span/i)[1]", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.click()`

Comment: The best thanks for me would be grade increasing or accepting of my answer ;)

Comment: I tried a few things and found out that when i reload the page and use your code it tells me `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'click') at <anonymous>:1:165` thats because `document.[...].singleNodeValue` returns `null` after i once cpied the XPATH from the Elements i can use it in the console but not with Tampermonkey... i tried it many times and all i did was copy XPATH nothing else.

PS: Allready upvoted for your help, but i cant because of less than 15 points.

Comment: So, the path is wrong. Try to find correct path with F12->CTRL-S